# How to execute script with xamarin forms on android

Tags: android, xamarin, scripting, mono, roslyn

I'm trying to run a C # script using Xamarin Forms on Android Mono.
When I run the script I get the error: **System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/mscorlib.dll"**

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
object result;
var script = CSharpScript.Create("DateTime.Today.Year",ScriptOptions.Default.WithImports("System"));
script.RunAsync().ContinueWith(s => result = s.Result).Wait();
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Flow: at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <fcbf47a04b2e4d90beafbae627e1fca4>:0 
at Roslyn.Utilities.FileUtilities.OpenFileStream (System.String path) [0x00032] in /_/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/FileSystem/FileUtilities.cs:415 
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromAssemblyInternal (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReferenceProperties properties, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DocumentationProvider documentation) [0x00054] in /_/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/MetadataReference/MetadataReference.cs:327